# Override .T (transpose) in subclass of numpy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, subclassing

I have a three dimensional dataset where the 1st dimension gives the type of the variable and the 2nd and 3rd dimensions are spatial indexes.  I am attempting to make this data more user friendly by creating a subclass of `ndarray` containing the data, but with attributes that have sensible names that point to the appropriate variable dimension.  One of the variable types is temperature, which I would like to represent with the attribute `.T`.  I attempt to set it like this:

```
self.T = self[8,:,:]
```

However, this clashes with the underlying numpy attribute for transposing an array.  Normally, overriding a class attribute is trivial, however in this case I get an exception when I try to re-write the attribute.  The following is a minimal example of the same problem:

```
import numpy as np

class foo(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, input_array):
        obj = np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)
        obj.T = 100.0
        return obj

foo([1,2,3,4])
```

results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmp.py", line 9, in <module>
    foo([1,2,3,4])
  File "tmp.py", line 6, in __new__
    obj.T = 100.0
AttributeError: attribute 'T' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects is not writable
```

I have tried using `setattr(obj, 'T', 100.0)` to set the attribute, but the result is the same.

Obviously, I could just give up and name my attribute `.temperature`, or something else.  However `.T` will be much more eloquent for the subsequent mathematical expressions which will be done with these data objects.  How can I force python/numpy to override this attribute?

Comment: I'd imagine that this is implemented in c, so you can't overwrite it for good reason. I think it's acceptable for numpy to place this restriction, because it could break any number of functions that leverage the `T` attribute, and then you have a broken numpy array. What's stopping you from using `T_`? or `temp`?

Comment: `T` is not an actual attribute. It's a descriptor like a property that retrieves a new object.

Comment: Try something like `@property def T(self): return self[8,:,:]`

Comment: You can't write new attributes to an array because it doesn't have a `__dict__`. In Python you can simulate that using `__slots__`

Comment: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/c2dd245047ff2eb80972600163ecac9048d74e1f/numpy/core/src/multiarray/getset.c#L1021

Comment: Why do you use new and not init for class constructor?

Comment: The code for `np.matrix` and `np.ma` is mostly python.  There you can see how they overwrite the `T` property.

Comment: @MadPhysicist That is the answer!  Thank you.

Comment: `ndarray` subclasses must implement `__new__`, not `__init__`, see [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html).

Comment: Since my comment was helpful, I went ahead and made it into an answer.

Comment: You are free to change your selection if you want, but the currently selected answer is quite good in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Mad Physicist and hpaulj's lead, the solution to my minimal working example is:

```
import numpy as np

class foo(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, input_array):
        obj = np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)
        return obj

    @property
    def T(self):
        return 100.0

x = foo([1,2,3,4])
print("T is", x.T)
```

Which results in:

```
T is [1 2 3 4]
```

Comment: You have an indentation issue

Comment: Your property is outside the class

Comment: Your output does not correlate with the code you posted

Answer (score 4):

For `np.matrix` subclass, as defined in np.matrixlib.defmatrix:

```
@property
def T(self):
    """
    Returns the transpose of the matrix.
    ....
    """
    return self.transpose()
```

Comment: Yes, this is the way to do it.  Thanks also to @MadPhysicist who answered as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

[`T`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html) is not a conventional attribute that lives in a [`__dict__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__) or [`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots). In fact, you can see this immediately because the result of `T` changes if you modify the shape or contents of an array.

Since [`ndarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) is a class written in C, it has special [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) for the dynamic attributes it exposes. `T` is one of these dynamic attributes, defined as a [`PyGetSetDef`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/structures.html#c.PyGetSetDef) structure. You can't override it by simple assignment, because there is nothing to assign to, but you can make a descriptor that overrides it at the class level.

As [@hpaulj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60879924/2988730) suggests, the simplest solution may be to use a [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) to implement the descriptor protocol for you:

```
import numpy as np

class foo(np.ndarray):
    @property
    def T(self):
        return self[8, :, :]
```

More complicated alternatives would be to make your own descriptor type, or even to extend the class in C and write your own `PyGetSetDef` structure. It all depends on what you are trying to achieve.