# How does the transpose instance "T" work in a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, class, recursion

I remember once I was writing a class and while defining the `__init__` method, I attempted to set an instance belonging to the same class, as in this example:

```
class Complex:
    def __init__(self, real, imag):
       self.real = real
       self.imag = imag
       self.conjugate = Complex(real, - imag) # instance of the same class

Compex(1, 2) # RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

But when I tried the code I soon realized that I had made my  `__init__` method recursive. As a result it would create an infinite loop, so I defined a method for my instance instead. I took that as a lesson and moved on until I found this way of transposing a matrix in numpy:

```
A = np.array([
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4]
])

A.T # array([[1, 3], [2, 4]])
```

My question is, how does this not cause an infinite loop as in my previous example?

Comment: `A.T` is a `property`, equivalent of `A.transpose()`.  That method returns a new array, a `view`, with different `shape` and `strides`.

Comment: Tranpose is just a view of the same object in memory, by changing the strides. It does not create new instances as your class example

Comment: @RichieV, a `view` is a new `ndarray`.

Comment: This is technically not an exact duplicate, but does a good job of answering your question anyway: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60877399/2988730. Both @hpaulj and I posted some answers there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the proper way to define your class, which also happens to be how numpy defines the transpose:

```
class Complex:
    def __init__(self, real, imag):
       self.real = real
       self.imag = imag

    @property
    def conjugate(self):
        return Complex(self.real, -self.imag)
```

By making the attributes a `property` computed on-demand, you can avoid recursion errors.

The transpose of an array creates a new array object with just the shape and strides reversed. Array data is not copied, so the operation is quite cheap.